Проблема с сервером майнкрафт
Здравстуйте, я заметел проблему на своём сервере мйанкрафт (хостинг на minecraft hosting pro) ошибка internal exception connection reset расположение - европа, сначала всё работала нормально, а потом всё, прикол в том что если я зайду через норм вай фай то мне выдаст выше указаную ошибку, а если включу точку доступа на телефоне и зайду на серв то всё ок, казалось бы что во всём виновата скорость вай фая, но нет, когда я зашёл на другой серв то всё окей и значит вай фай не причём, в конфиге нечего интересного нет, если нужна какая-то информация, пишите в коменты, связаться со мной wexorig1@gmail.com

то мне выдаст выше указаную ошибку - ошибка указана настолько высоко, что не поместилась в "вопрос"? Да и как такового вопроса то не прозвучало...

Извините , ошибка internal exception connection reset

Есть подозрения что ваша проблема заключается в некорректной работе нашей сетевой инфраструктуры, у меня тоже не открываются некоторые зарубежные сервисы и помогает использование мобильного интернета или впн сервисов. Почему вы выбрали европейский сервер? Есть ли возможность использовать другие места размещения сервера? Так же попробуйте зайти на свой сервер под ВПН чтобы подтвердить догадку
